# Solve the inequality $\frac{3-x}{x^2-2x-3}\le\frac{3-x}{x^2+2x-3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the inequality $$\dfrac{3-x}{x^2-2x-3}\le\dfrac{3-x}{x^2+2x-3}$$
We have $D: \begin{cases}x^2-2x-3\ne0\Rightarrow x\ne -1;3 \\ x^2+2x-3\ne0\Rightarrow x\ne-3;1\end{cases}$

Is the given equality equivalent (in $D$) to $$x^2-2x-3\ge x^2+2x-3\\\iff x\le0$$ So the solutions are $x\le0\cap D$? It seems like the inequalities I wrote aren't equivalent, because I don't get the answer.

Comment: Hint: It depends on whether $3-x<0,$ or $3-x>0.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thank you for the response! What depends on whether $3-x<0$, or $3-x>0$?

Comment: @Medi Why $x \le 0$? Also, it looks like you just canceled out the numerators, but you can't do that without checking the sign first.

Comment: @dxiv, because that's the solution to the inequality.

Comment: Well, the whole problem. But specifically whether it is equivalent to $$x^2-2x-3\geq x^2+2x-3$$

Comment: Begin by grouping everything in the Left Hand Side. Otherwise it is too complicated...

Comment: @Medi "*because that's the solution*" You are trying to find the solution, so you can't use the solution to solve it.

Comment: @dxiv, what do you mean? The solution of the inequality $$x^2-2x-3\ge x^2+2x-3$$ is $x\in(-\infty;0]$...

Comment: @Medi But that inequality is nowhere justified and, in fact, wrong.

Comment: @dxiv, that's' the whole point of my question. Why isn't there an equivalence...

Comment: @Medi You wrote in the question that the answer is wrong, so you know that. But we can't guess why it's wrong if you don't explain the steps that got you there.

Comment: You can't divide both sides by $x-3$ if you don't know if $x-3 < 0$ or $x-3> 0$ or if $x - 3=0$.  And you can't assume $\frac 1{x^2 -2x -3} \le \frac 1{x^2 + 2x-3} \implies x^2 -2x -3 \ge x^2 +2x -3$ unless you know that both $x^2 -2x-3$ and $x^2 +2x -3$ are *both* positive.  I think it is *ESSENTIAL* that you review how inequality signs work when you manipulate negative numbers.  This is simply something you can NOT fudge.

Comment: Hint:  It might help you to realize $x^2 - 2x -3 = (x-3)(x+1)$ and $x^2 +2x -3 = (x+3)(x-1)$.  Or maybe not.

Answer (score 4):

**hint**

For $ x\notin\{-1,1,-3,3\}$, the inequation is equivalent to

$$(3-x)\Bigl(\frac{1}{(x-1)(x+3)}-\frac{1}{(x+1)(x-3)}\Bigr)\ge 0$$

$$\iff x(x-1)(x+1)(x+3)\ge 0$$

You will find that the solution is

$$S=(-\infty,-3)\cup(-1,0]\cup(1,3)\cup(3,+\infty)$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{3-x}{x^2-2x-3}\le\dfrac{3-x}{x^2+2x-3}$$
$$\implies(3-x)\Bigl(\dfrac1{x^2-2x-3}-\dfrac1{x^2+2x-3}\Bigr)\le0$$
$$\implies(3-x)\Bigl(\dfrac{x^2+2x-3-x^2+2x+3}{(x-3)(x+1)(x+3)(x-1)}\Bigr)\le0$$
$$\implies (3-x)\Bigl(\dfrac{4x}{(x-3)(x+1)(x+3)(x-1)}\Bigr)\le0$$
$$\implies \dfrac{4x}{(x+1)(x+3)(x-1)}\ge0$$
$$\implies x\in(\infty, -3)\cup(-1,0]\cup(1,3)\cup(3,\infty)$$

Answer (score 1):

No.  That is not valid.

If $3-x > 0$ then $\frac {3-x}{x^2 -2x-3} \le \frac {3-x}{x^2+2x -3} \implies \frac 1{x^2-2x -3} \le \frac 1{x^2 +2x -3}$ but

if $3-x < 0$ then $\frac {3-x}{x^2-2x-3} \le \frac {3-x}{x^2+2x-3} \implies \frac 1{x^2-2x-3} \ge \frac 1{x^2 + 2x -3}$.

And if $3-x = 0$ then from $\frac {3-x}{x^2-2x-3} \le \frac {3-x}{x^2+2x-3}$ we can not conclude *anything* about $\frac 1{x^2 -2x-3}$ and $\frac 1{x^2+2x -3}$.

Furthermore.  If $x^2 -2x-3$ and $x^2+2x -3$ are both positive of both negative then yes, $\frac 1{x^2 - 2x -3} \le \frac 1{x^2 +2x -3} \implies x^2+2x -3 \le x^2 -2x -3$ but if one is positive and the other negative you can not reach that conclusion.

The reason is:

Axiom:  If $a < b$ and $m > 0$ then $am < bm$.
Proposition:  If $a < b$ and $m < 0$ then $am > bm$.
Obvious fact: If $m =0$ then $am =bm=0$ no matter what $a$ and $b$ are.
Proposition: If $m > 0$ then $\frac 1m > 0$; if $m < 0$ then $\frac 1m < 0$ and if $m=0$ then $\frac 1m$ is meaningless gutterwash.

Therefore if $3-x > 0$ then $\frac 1{3-x} > 0$ so

$\frac {3-x}{x^2 -2x -3} \le \frac {3-x}{x^2+2-3} \implies$

$\frac {3-x}{x^2-2x-3}\cdot \frac 1{3-x} \le \frac {3-x}{x^2 + 2-3} \implies$

$\frac 1{x^2-2x -3} \le \frac 1{x^2+2-3}$.

But if $3-x < 0$ then $\frac 1{3-x} < 0$ so

$\frac {3-x}{x^2 -2x -3} \le \frac {3-x}{x^2+2-3} \implies$

$\frac {3-x}{x^2-2x-3}\cdot \frac 1{3-x} \ge \frac {3-x}{x^2 + 2-3} \implies$

$\frac 1{x^2-2x -3} \ge \frac 1{x^2+2-3}$.

And if $3-x = 0$ then

$\frac {3-x}{x^2 - 2x -3} \le \frac {3-x}{x^2+2-3}\implies$

$\frac 0{x^2 -2x -3} \le \frac 0{x^2+2-3}\implies$

$0 = 0$.

Furthermore.  If $x^2 -2x-3$ and $x^2 +2x -3$ are both positive then

$\frac 1{x^2-2x-3} \le \frac 1{x^2 + 2x -3} \implies$

$1 \le \frac {x^2-2x -3}{x^2 + 2x -3} \implies$

$x^2 + 2x -3 \le x^2 -2x -3$.

But if $x^2 -2x -3$ and $x^2 + 2x -3$ are both negative then

$\frac 1{x^2-2x -3} \le 1{x^2+2x-3}\implies$

$1 \ge \frac {x^2-2x-3}{x^2 +2x -3} \implies$

$x^2 + 2x-3 \le x^2 -2x-3$.

However if $x^2 -2x -3 < 0$ and $x^2 + 2x -3 > 0$ then

$\frac 1{x^2 -2x -3} \le \frac 1{x^2 + 2x -3} \implies$

$1 \ge \frac {x^2 -2x-3}{x^2+2x -3}\implies$

$x^2 + 2x -3 \ge x^2 -2x -3$.

But we didn't actually need to do this because if $x^2 -2x -3 < 0 < x^2 + 2x-3$ we knew that to begin with.

And if $x^2 +2x -3 < 0 < x^2 -2x -3$ then $\frac 1{x^2 +2x -3 } < 0$ and $\frac 1{x^2 -2x -3} > 0$ so $\frac 1{x^2-2x -3} \le \frac 1{x^2+2x -3}$ would not be possible in the first place.

.......

So would *do* we do?

Note $x^2 - 2x -3 = (x-3)(x+1)$ and $x^2+2x -3= (x+3)(x-1)$. And $3-x = -(x-3)$.

$\frac {3-x}{x^2 -2x -3} \le \frac {3-x}{x^2 +2x-3} \implies$

$-\frac {x-3}{(x-3)(x+1)}\le -\frac {x-3}{(x+3)(x-1)}\implies $

$-\frac 1{x+1}\le -\frac{x-3}{(x+3)(x-1)};x\ne 3\implies$

$\frac 1{x+1}\ge \frac {x-3}{(x+3)(x-1)}x\ne 3$

Now we can multiply both sides but $(x+1)(x-1)(x+3)$ ***!!!BUT!!!*** we *must* take into account whether those factors are positive or negative.

Case 1: :  $x >1$.  Then all three are positive and $(x+1)(x-1)(x+3) > 0$ then

$\frac 1{x+1}\ge \frac {x-3}{(x+3)(x-1)}x\ne 3\implies$

$(x+3)(x-1) \ge (x-3)(x+1);x\ne 3;x\ne -3;x\ne 1;x\ne -1\implies$

$x^2 +2x -3\ge x^2 -2x +1;x\ne 3;x\ne -3; x\ne 1; x\ne -1\implies$

$4x \ge 0; x\ne 3; x\ne -3;x\ne 1; x\ne -1\implies$

$x \ge 0; x\ne 3; x\ne 1$ and $x > 1$ so $x>1; x\ne 3$ is one range of solutions.

Case 2:  $-1 < x < 1$.  Then $x+1, x+3$ are positive but $x-1$ is negative so $(x+1)(x-1)(x+3) < 0$. so we do the same as above but we flip the inequality sig.

$\frac 1{x+1}\ge \frac {x-3}{(x+3)(x-1)}x\ne 3\implies$

$(x+3)(x-1) \le (x-3)(x+1);x\ne 3;x\ne -3;x\ne 1;x\ne -1\implies$

$x^2 +2x -3\le x^2 -2x +1;x\ne 3;x\ne -3; x\ne 1; x\ne -1\implies$

$4x \le 0; x\ne 3; x\ne -3;x\ne 1; x\ne -1\implies$

$x \le 0; x\ne -3; x\ne -1$ and $-1 < x < 1$ so $-1 < x \le 0$ is another range of solutions.

Case 3: $-3 < x < -1$.  Then $x+1$ is positive and $x-1, x-3$ are negative so $(x+1)(x-1)(x+3) > 0$ so we do the same as case 1.

$\frac 1{x+1}\ge \frac {x-3}{(x+3)(x-1)}x\ne 3\implies$

$(x+3)(x-1) \ge (x-3)(x+1);x\ne 3;x\ne -3;x\ne 1;x\ne -1\implies$

$x^2 +2x -3\ge x^2 -2x +1;x\ne 3;x\ne -3; x\ne 1; x\ne -1\implies$

$4x \ge 0; x\ne 3; x\ne -3;x\ne 1; x\ne -1\implies$

$x \ge 0; x\ne 3; x\ne 1$ !*BUT*! $-3 < x < -1$ and that is a contradiction so no solutions exist in this range.

Case 4: $x < -3$.  Then all three terms are negative and $(x-1)(x-1)(x+3) < 0$ and we flip the inequality sign.

$\frac 1{x+1}\ge \frac {x-3}{(x+3)(x-1)}x\ne 3\implies$

$(x+3)(x-1) \le (x-3)(x+1);x\ne 3;x\ne -3;x\ne 1;x\ne -1\implies$

$x^2 +2x -3\le x^2 -2x +1;x\ne 3;x\ne -3; x\ne 1; x\ne -1\implies$

$4x \le 0; x\ne 3; x\ne -3;x\ne 1; x\ne -1\implies$

$x \le 0; x\ne -3; x\ne -1$ and $x< -3$ so $x<-3$ is another range of solutions.

So the total range of solutions is $x \in (-\infty, -3)\cup (-1, 0]\cup (1,3)\cup (3\infty)$.